# Tracking usages of code across a SVN repository

Tags: svn, usage-tracking

I'm working on a library and am curious if my changes will break other projects in the Subversion repository which use it, so I'd like to search for usages of methods across all of the projects in the repository.

I'm curious what my best option is.  I've tried downloading all projects to disk and using an indexer to search, but that approach seems pretty clunky (and I have to update the projects periodically).

I use IntelliJ 9, so I'm curious if there is a plug-in for it to do this sort of thing (or built-in ability).  Doing a search in "Projects and Libraries" isn't a wide enough search.

FishEye seems to support this, has anyone tried that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of several options:

- [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) will cross-reference functions with callsites, which can be very useful to see where functions are being used across the codebase
- [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) has some options to index caller/callees, though I think this can be very slow
- Set up a build server such as [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) and create a job that builds every project at least once a day.  This will give you the best indication that you are not introducing breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  With GNU Global you have to have the source code on disk?

Comment: Yes, you need to do a full checkout and then run Global over the whole source tree.